# MPTK 2 does not detect PT 10

Tags: pro-tools

I recently installed pt 10 on my macpro 2 x 2,4GHZ quadcore Intel Xenon westmere 24gb ram but MPTK 2 does not detect PT 10 as a valid PT install. I tried to install MPTK 2 from the installer disk aswell from my account. Can anybody help me or has anybody encounterd the same problem. Due to this problem i'm not able to use the disk cach function in PT 10.

regards Adrian

Answer (score 1):

I believe 10 doesn't support the Music Production Toolkit or DV Toolkit., only the Complete Production Toolkit. A lot of the features of the previous Toolkits have been incoporated into the base software. Upgrade paths from MPTK/DVTK to CPTK are still available.

Comment: Correct, it's only PT10, PT10+CPTK, or PT10HD

Answer (score 0):

I think mptk has been eliminated from the product line. Now you can have pt10, or pt10 with cptk, or pt10hd software.